# Personalizar error 404 Adonisjs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, api, adonisjs

Tengo una `API` desarrollada en `Adonis JS`, la cual la consumo desde el `front` desarrollado con `Angular`,
de la `API` regreso un `JSON` para que el `front` lo interprete, todo funciona muy bien, pero quiero personalizar los `errores 404 y 500` para que el usuario no vea la `vista` por `defaul` de `adonis`,
He intentado lo siguiente:

```
Route.get('*', ({ view }) => {
    return view.render('404');
}) 
Route.post('*', ({ view }) => {
    return view.render('404');
})
```

esto me muestra la vista con mi error personalizado, para el `get` no tengo tema ya que si me regresa el `error` cuando la ruta no existe o esta mal algo en el controlador asignado, pero para las `rutas` que están con `post` me muestra para todas la vita `404` cuando la ruta `si existe` y todo esta bien.

```
Versión de Adonis 4.1.0
```

Comment: Que versión de adonis?

Comment: @BetaM la versión que utilizo es  4.1.0

Comment: La doc. Recomienda crear un handler https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/exceptions